# PHP form to store data in text file not working

Tags: php, forms, file

My simple PHP code is not working and I dont know why.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="phpform.php" method="post">
<label for = "name">Name : </label>
<input type="text" name="name" required><br>
<input type="submit">
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
$names=$_POST['name'];
$fp = fopen('txtfiles/FirstNames.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $names);
fclose($fp);
}
```

After pressing "Submit" button webpage resets (as it should), but when I open "FirstNames.txt" it is empty. No error messages, no nothing.

Thank You for Your help.

Comment: Is this the source code for your phpform.php or is that another script?

Comment: @RocketNuts what You see here is my whole source code named phpform.php

Comment: FYI, you can combine the 3 lines that open/write/close into `file_put_contents('txtfiles/FirstNames.txt', $names, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: @Barmar still not working

Comment: I never said it would fix it, it's just a simpler way of doing the same thing.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the pathname. Try using an absolute path.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the script so you'll be sure to see warnings.

Comment: I think the current or working dir for this script is something else than your expect.
Try to use an explicit absolute path for your text file, e.g. something like '/home/helperman2000/txtfiles/FirstNames.txt' (of course make sure the directory exists).

Comment: Or force to put the .txt file in the same dir as your phpform.php like this: `file_put_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/FirstNames.txt', $names, FILE_APPEND);`

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

Add this so we can see what is happening

```
<pre>
    <?= print_r($_POST, true) ?>
</pre>
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['name']) )
{
    $names = $_POST['name'];
    $file = 'txtfiles/FirstNames.txt'; // put file name in its own variable
    if ( ! file_exists($file) ) {
        // File should already exist
        throw new Exception('File does not exist');
    }
    echo realpath($file); // where is it really?
    $fp = fopen($file, 'a');
    if ( ! $fp ) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to open file');
    }
    fwrite($fp, $names);
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    echo "\$_POST['name'] does not exist";
}
```